# Why would new Date return invalid in the mongo shell when it returns a valid date in Node REPL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

In Mongo (technically RoboMongo):

```
db.audit.find({source: "junebug"}).limit(50).forEach(function (doc){

  print(JSON.stringify(doc)); 
  print(doc.start);
  doc.startDt = new Date(doc.start + 'Z');

  print(doc.startDt);
});
```

produces things like:

```
{"_id":{},"source":"junebug","maxDays":0.05,"start":"2016-11-03 00:00:00","end":"2016-11-03 00:59:59" ...
2016-11-03 00:00:00
Invalid Date
```

So, `"2016-11-03 00:00:00"+"Z"` is invalid. But in the Node REPL:

```
> var d = new Date("2016-11-03 04:00:00"+"Z")
undefined
> d
2016-11-03T04:00:00.000Z
```

Looks valid. Is valid. I'm at a loss to explain why this would be happening. I can't imagine there would be a difference in date parsing between Node 6 and Mongo's js engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongodb Date Object Only accept Following Parameters.

You can specify a particular date by passing to the Date() method a datetime string. For example:

new Date("YYYY-mm-dd") which returns the ISODate with the specified date.

new Date("YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:ss") which specifies the datetime in local datetime and returns the ISODate with the specified datetime in UTC.

new Date("YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:ssZ") which specifies the datetime in UTC and returns the ISODate with the specified datetime in UTC.

your format is invalid that is why it is giving an error.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/

Comment: Removing the `+ "Z"` doesn't change anything.

Comment: Mongodb Date object only accept following parameters

new Date("<YYYY-mm-dd>") which returns the ISODate with the specified date.
•new Date("<YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:ss>") which specifies the datetime in local datetime and returns the ISODate with the specified datetime in UTC.
•new Date("<YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:ssZ>") which specifies the datetime in UTC and returns the ISODate with the specified datetime in UTC.

your format is invalid. that's why it is giving error

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/